# How to check if remote login works before redirecting with php?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

i am logging into my webmail remotely with a custom login form, which works absolutely fine, my problem is if an incorrect user/pass is entered.

If the details are correct and you press the logn button, it takes you direct to your webmail inbox, whereas if the details are incorrect it will still redirect you but to the original webmail login form (which i don't want users to be able to see/get to).

My question is, is it possible to check that the thing is going to login correctly before redirecting so i can show incorrect user/pass entered rather than redirecting, and only redirect if the login details are good.

I thought this may be possible through curl, but my abilities with curl are only limited.
Here is my redirect code (this is what fires after the form is submitted)

```
$u = urlencode($_POST['webmail_user']);
$pw = urlencode($_POST['webmail_pass']);
$gu = urlencode("/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php");
$port = 2095; 
$protocol = "http://";
$domain = "domain.com";
$redirect_to = $protocol.$domain.":".$port."/login/?user=".$u."&pass=".$pw."&goto_uri=".$gu."&dest_uri=".$gu;
header("Location: ".$redirect_to);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to achieve is need additional step for checking the input value's validity.

Without revealing its process to the end user, it can be done with the following method:

1) AJAX : make ajax page that executes curl requesting to the server, check the account's login process and return whether it is working well or not.

---

For your information, I will add detail explanation of this.

Let's say there are two file like the following: index.php, auth_check.php.

### index.php

1. Call the auth_check.php using AJAX. For implementing AJAX using jQUERY, refer to the following link:
   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
2. With the result of auth_check.php, we will know whether the account info is working or not.
3. Show error message to the user or try to move next step

### auth_step.php

1. Get HTTP result (HTML) for both valid account info and invalid one.
2. You parse the HTML source and make decision function that can classify those two situations.
3. Implementing HTTP request part (sign in) using curl.
4. Print out the result that derived from #2's function. (index.php will catch this as a result)

---

2) IFrame : embed Iframe into the original page and communicate it to verify the login as describe in above.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: for some reason iframe doesn't work, so i guess it will have to be ajax, but i'm not too familiar with ajax. Could you point me in the right direction of what i require? thanks

Comment: I will add it in above.